# How do I obtain an animal companion?

Tags: dnd-5e, animal-companions

coming originally from 3rd edition DnD and recently started 5e, I'm a little bit confused about the use of animal companions in 5e.

Is there any possibility to obtain an animal companion outside the Beastmaster Ranger class?
Did the Druid really lose its ability to have a companion in 5e? Or is there a workaround to make an animal becoming loyal to a character? Maybe through animal handling plus some magic?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, as I think it has been asked before. Let us know if that question is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did. So sad, that animal companions aren't a real thing anymore in 5e.

Comment: @TheKhileyan - as a side note, you can choose Urchin as a background which comes with a pet mouse. My DMs in the past have been "nice" in that it does not get carbonised or erradicated every time I find myself in a area-of-effect spell or monster feature like a dragon's breath weapon. :)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.